# Multi-Database Multi-Schemas do't seem to work in newer versions of postgresql

Tags: postgresql, schema

I have a problem where I want to create two databases 
and two schemas. Each database will have a separate schema.
The public schema has been dropped. I have tried this without dropping 
the public schema with the same result. When connecting to the database with the database and schema owner the schema cannot be seen or used.

I have set up single databases with an schema, but never tried to set up more than one. The problem sees to come from multiple databases and schemas.

```
create user tom;
create database fishes owner tom encoding = 'UTF8';
create schema fish authorization tom;
alter database fishes set schema 'fish';
create user harry;
create database lizards owner harry encoding = 'UTF8';
create schema lizard authorization harry;
alter database lizards set schema 'lizard';

psql (10.8)
postgres=# create user tom;
CREATE ROLE
postgres=# create database fishes owner tom encoding = 'UTF8';
CREATE DATABASE
postgres=# create schema fish authorization tom;
CREATE SCHEMA
postgres=# alter database fishes set schema 'fish';
ALTER DATABASE
postgres=# \du
                                   List of roles
 Role name |                         Attributes                         | Member of
-----------+------------------------------------------------------------+-----------
 postgres  | Superuser, Create role, Create DB, Replication, Bypass RLS | {}
 tom       |                                                            | {}


postgres=# \l
                                                 List of databases
   Name    |  Owner   | Encoding |          Collate           |           Ctype            |   Access privileges
-----------+----------+----------+----------------------------+----------------------------+-----------------------
 fishes    | tom      | UTF8     | English_United States.1252 | English_United States.1252 |
 postgres  | postgres | UTF8     | English_United States.1252 | English_United States.1252 |
 template0 | postgres | UTF8     | English_United States.1252 | English_United States.1252 | =c/postgres          +
           |          |          |                            |                            | postgres=CTc/postgres
 template1 | postgres | UTF8     | English_United States.1252 | English_United States.1252 | =c/postgres          +
           |          |          |                            |                            | postgres=CTc/postgres
(4 rows)


postgres=# \dn
List of schemas
 Name | Owner
------+-------
 fish | tom
(1 row)
postgres=# create user harry;
CREATE ROLE
postgres=# create database lizards owner harry encoding = 'UTF8';
CREATE DATABASE
postgres=# create schema lizard authorization harry;
CREATE SCHEMA
postgres=# alter database lizards set schema 'lizard';
ALTER DATABASE
postgres=# \du
                                   List of roles
 Role name |                         Attributes                         | Member of
-----------+------------------------------------------------------------+-----------
 harry     |                                                            | {}
 postgres  | Superuser, Create role, Create DB, Replication, Bypass RLS | {}
 tom       |                                                            | {}


postgres=# \l
                                                 List of databases
   Name    |  Owner   | Encoding |          Collate           |           Ctype            |   Access privileges
-----------+----------+----------+----------------------------+----------------------------+-----------------------
 fishes    | tom      | UTF8     | English_United States.1252 | English_United States.1252 |
 lizards   | harry    | UTF8     | English_United States.1252 | English_United States.1252 |
 postgres  | postgres | UTF8     | English_United States.1252 | English_United States.1252 |
 template0 | postgres | UTF8     | English_United States.1252 | English_United States.1252 | =c/postgres          +
           |          |          |                            |                            | postgres=CTc/postgres
 template1 | postgres | UTF8     | English_United States.1252 | English_United States.1252 | =c/postgres          +
           |          |          |                            |                            | postgres=CTc/postgres
(5 rows)


postgres=# \dn
List of schemas
  Name  | Owner
--------+-------
 fish   | tom
 lizard | harry
(2 rows)

postgres=# alter user tom password  'xxx';
ALTER ROLE
postgres=# alter user harry password  'xxx';
ALTER ROLE

when I did a \dnpsql -U tom fishes
Password for user tom:
psql (10.8)
WARNING: Console code page (437) differs from Windows code page (1252)
         8-bit characters might not work correctly. See psql reference
         page "Notes for Windows users" for details.
Type "help" for help.

fishes=> \l
                                                 List of databases
   Name    |  Owner   | Encoding |          Collate           |           Ctype            |   Access privileges
-----------+----------+----------+----------------------------+----------------------------+-----------------------
 fishes    | tom      | UTF8     | English_United States.1252 | English_United States.1252 |
 lizards   | harry    | UTF8     | English_United States.1252 | English_United States.1252 |
 postgres  | postgres | UTF8     | English_United States.1252 | English_United States.1252 |
 template0 | postgres | UTF8     | English_United States.1252 | English_United States.1252 | =c/postgres          +
           |          |          |                            |                            | postgres=CTc/postgres
 template1 | postgres | UTF8     | English_United States.1252 | English_United States.1252 | =c/postgres          +
           |          |          |                            |                            | postgres=CTc/postgres
(5 rows)


fishes=> \du
                                   List of roles
 Role name |                         Attributes                         | Member of
-----------+------------------------------------------------------------+-----------
 harry     |                                                            | {}
 postgres  | Superuser, Create role, Create DB, Replication, Bypass RLS | {}
 tom       |                                                            | {}


fishes=> \dn
  List of schemas
  Name  |  Owner
--------+----------
 public | postgres
(1 row)


fishes=> show search_path;
 search_path
-------------
 fish
(1 row)

fishes=> create table eels( type varchar(30) primary key );
ERROR:  no schema has been selected to create in
LINE 1: create table eels( type varchar(30) primary key );
                     ^
fishes=> create table fish.eels( type varchar(30) primary key );
ERROR:  schema "fish" does not exist
LINE 1: create table fish.eels( type varchar(30) primary key );
                     ^
```

I would expect when I logged in with either user that when I logged in with one of my non-postgres users that \dn would show the schema for the database that is show with the show search_path. Search_path is correct. Also it seems that access is not granted to the owner of the schema.

Comment: It looks like you are creating the schemas in whatever database you are first connected to.  After creating the fishes database, you need to connect to that database before creating the schema.

Comment: Thank you, your suggestion worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is as Jeremy suggested in his comment.

Before creating the schema connect to the database you want to create the schema in.
There is no create schema syntax that includes the database name it should be created in, so it needs to be done this way.